Facing an exception when closing a Fragment using android kotlin
I have a main activity, in that I have a fragment layout. Based on the condition, I would like to show the corresponding fragment.
So, From the main activity, I am calling a class where I am doing functionalities and calling the fragment
MainActivity --> TestingClass --> FragmentA/FragmentB/FragmentC
After I had obtained the result from the fragment(FragmentA/FragmentB) I wanted to close that fragment (I mean I tried to remove it from the activity).
So, from mainactivity, I have passed the fragment manager to the TestingClass. By calling the snippet below I am trying to remove the fragment.
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()

But, I am facing below error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.testing.android.tipHandlerUI.TestingClass, but got kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref$ObjectRef

I recommend that you expand your [mcve] quite a bit. In particular, please show the entire stack trace, not just one line of it.

Dont hold direct instance of fragment in a object as this can cause a leak.
You can get the instance of current fragment object like below code when it is required.
val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentInActive(R.id.your_fragment_container_id)

then you can remove it with your same code
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()

But as Xml flow is always prone to error in runtime cover it with try catch block so app doesn't crash
Cheers!!
